# exporting large files to excel using PHPExcel

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpexcel

I am trying to export around 40,000 rows of Mysql data in PHP(Laravel4) using PHPExcel library.
Below is my code:

($patList is an array of result columns)

```
set_time_limit ( 3000 );

$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;

$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => -1);

PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$i = 1;
$patList = $result[0];

for ($r = 0; $r < count($patList); $r++) {

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)

         ->setCellValue("A$i", $patList[$r][0])
         ->setCellValue("B$i", $patList[$r][1])
         ->setCellValue("C$i", $patList[$r][2])
         ->setCellValue("D$i", $patList[$r][1])
         ->setCellValue("E$i", $patList[$r][2])
         ->setCellValue("F$i", $patList[$r][1])
         ->setCellValue("G$i", $patList[$r][2])
         ->setCellValue("H$i", $patList[$r][2])
         ->setCellValue("I$i", $patList[$r][1])
         ->setCellValue("J$i", $patList[$r][2])
         ->setCellValue("K$i", $patList[$r][5]);
     $i++;
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name of Sheet 1');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="result.xls"');

header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

ob_clean();

flush();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The above code runs fine if there are 3-4 columns in the excel and 15,000 rows. However, if I increase the no. of rows to 30,000 or the no. of columns to 10, the excel doesn't get generated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is error reporting enabled? Make sure your script doesn't run out of memory, because you are keeping pretty big variables in memory.

Comment: Try setting `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` or whatever you feel would be enough memory for the script.

Comment: Yes that's working now! It was consuming 228 MB Memory which is why it was failing. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => -1);
```

isn't sensible.... I don't even know if using a value of -1 will work; but if it does, it will  mean that you're storing everything in memory and nothing in php://temp

The `memoryCacheSize` value tells the cache stream how much data should be stored in memory before switching data out to php://temp ; so

```
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '8MB');
```

would tell the cache stream to use 8MB of memory, and then if additional data needed to be stored to use php://temp instead

Comment: Oh, that's helpful. I had increased the cache size also to 500M, still it was failing. Because the memory limit itself was not sufficient. So, now after I set the memory_limit to 500M or 1024M, it works !