# How to export an Excel with 60k+ rows in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel-4

I have a file which downloads excel in Laravel 4.2

the view page looks like this

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    require(app_path().'/libs/excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("ideconnect.com")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("ideconnect.com")
                                 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                 ->setCategory("Test result file");

    $arr = array();

            $users1 = User::where('event','=',$exceleve)->orderby('name')->with(array('answer'=>function($q) use($qid1){

                $q->where('question_id','=','3104')->orWhere('question_id','=','3105');

            }))->get();

    $user_ids=array();
    foreach($users1 as $us){
        if($us->answer[0]->answer_text!='' && ($us->role!='admin_dd' || $us->role!='sales_dd')){
            $user_ids[] = $us->id;
        }
    }

        $userswithanswers = User::whereIn('id', $user_ids)
                        ->with('answer')
                        ->get();


    foreach($userswithanswers as $usa){

        $tempansarr = array();
        $tempcatansarr = array();

        foreach($usa->answer as $ansobj){
            $tempansarr[$ansobj->question_id] = $ansobj->answer_text;
        }

        foreach($usa->categoryvendoranswer as $catansobj){
            $tempcatansarr[$catansobj->categoryvendor_id] = $catansobj->answer;
        }

        $useransarr[$usa->id]['login'] = $usa->email;
        $useransarr[$usa->id]['id'] = $usa->id;
        $useransarr[$usa->id]['answers'] = $tempansarr;
        $useransarr[$usa->id]['catanswers'] = $tempcatansarr;
     //dd($tempcatansarr);
    }

    $questions = Question::orderBy('page')->where('event' ,'=',$exceleve)->where('page' ,'!=',0)->orderBy('order')->get();
    //$categoryvendors = Categoryvendor::all();


    // HEADER ROW FOR FOR EXCEL
    $header1 = array();$header1[]='';
    $header2 = array();$header2[]='Login';
    $preprojectnumber = '';

    foreach($questions as $header){
        /*echo $header->class_name."<br>";
        echo $header->question_group."<br>";*/
        $header3[] = "Page_".$header->page;
        if($header->class_name !='projects checkbox group'){
            //echo "1";
            $header1[] = $header->question_group;
            $header2[] = $header->question_text;

        } else {
            if($header->question_group!=$preprojectnumber){
                $header1[] = $header['question_group'];
                $header2[] = 'Stage of Buying Cycle';

            }
            $preprojectnumber = $header->question_group;

        }

    }

$excelarr = array();
//dd($useransarr);


foreach($useransarr as $usarr){

        $b=array();
        $b[]=$usarr['login'];
        $preprojectnumber = '';
        $tempvar = '';
        $counter=0;

// dd($usarr['answers']);

    foreach($questions as $question){
            if($question->class_name!='projects checkbox group'){ 
                $b[] = $usarr['answers'][$question->id];
            } 
            else 
            {
                if($question->question_group!=$preprojectnumber){
                    $counter=1;
                    $tempvar = $usarr['answers'][$question->id];
                    if($usarr['answers'][$question->id]!=''){$tempvar = $tempvar.', ';}
                } else {
                    $tempvar = $tempvar.$usarr['answers'][$question->id];
                    if($usarr['answers'][$question->id]!=''){$tempvar = $tempvar.', ';}
                }
                    $preprojectnumber = $question->question_group;
                    $counter++;
                    if($counter==5){
                            $b[]=$tempvar;
                    }
            }
    }
    $excelarr[] = $b;
}

array_unshift($excelarr, $header1);
array_unshift($excelarr, $header2);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->fromArray($excelarr, '', 'A1');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($exceleve);

$styleArray = array(
      'font' => array(
        'name' => 'Calibri',
        'size' => '10',
        'color' => array(
            'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
        ),
        'bold' => true,
      ),
      'fill' => array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array(
          'rgb' => '000000',
        ),
      ),
    );


$styleArray2 = array(
      'font' => array(
        'name' => 'Calibri',
        'size' => '10',
        'color' => array(
            'rgb' => '000000'
        ),
        'bold' => true,
      ),

      'fill' => array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array(
          'rgb' => 'cccccc',
        ),
      ),
    );

$styleArray3 = array(
      'font' => array(
        'name' => 'Calibri',
        'size' => '8',
        ),
    );


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($styleArray3);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A2:LA2')->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A1:LA1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="event-data.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');


 // dd('aaa');
//ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit;
```

This Code runs very well if the number of rows are less , But if the data increase it is throwing

`Memory Limit reach`

I just want to know placing this code inside Queue will solve the problem ??

if yes then how should I dot that

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545538/exporting-large-files-to-excel-using-phpexcel

Comment: @DusanKasan I have already tried that its not working

Comment: I was working with large xls and only one advice that I can give you is to write everything to CSV and then in backgroud queue export from CSV to XLS (depending on what server you have). It dosen't make sens to working with big parts of data in the browser - esspecialy with XLS with is huge metadata file format.

Answer (score 0):

You should try implementing Cell Caching, as described here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md#cell-caching

Instead of trying to keep all the data in memory, some of it will be cached on disk or in a database. This reduces the amount of memory PHPExcel needs.
The drawback is that the processing will now take longer (and it seems to be exponential).

As an alternative, you can try using Spout: https://github.com/box/spout. It is able to parse spreadsheets regardless of their size, using not more than 3MB of memory. You won't find as many features as in PHPExcel but all the features you used in your example seem to be supported.